# Get length of a line stored in SQL Server Geometry column with srid 4326

Tags: sql, geometry, epsg, st-geometry

I have some spatial data stored in SQL database geometry column called sp_geography (The field is defined as Geometry). The SQL below:

```sql
f.sp_geography.STLength()
```

returns, for example 0.0895991008150951 when I was expecting 892.9m and 0.00175496077867079 when I was expecting 132.6m

I believe it is returning decimal degrees but I cannot workout how to convert to metres. How can I retun the result in metres?

Comment: To solve your problem you must change your coordinate system into metric coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks Vincent but I'm still struggling.. is this something I can do within the select statement or do I have to actually change how the spatial data is store?

Comment: On PostGIS, I know you can do that in the select statement but i don't know for SQL Server, I have no experience with it.